# Complicated function declaration in c

Tags: c, function, declaration

I have a question about a line of code that I cant really figure out

```
int *(*func)(int a, float b);
```

I can't seem to understand what this means , is it a pointer to a pointer that points in a function that returns int ?

Comment: It's a variable declaration, not a function declaration. The variable name is `func`, and the variable type is "pointer to a function that takes an `int` value and a `float` value as input, and returns an `int*` value as output".

Comment: Thanks a lot for a fast answer !

Comment: See this tool: http://cdecl.org/ - which unfortunately doesn't work if your variable is called `func`, apparently, but is otherwise very useful for this kind of task.

Answer (score 3):

No, read it from inside out, it's a pointer to a function, which takes two arguments, an `int` and a `float`, and returns a pointer to `int`.